# How can I get original AST by trait identifier with syntax extensions?

Tags: rust, metaprogramming, traits, rust-compiler-plugin

I've gotten stuck, when I tried to implement traits programmatically using syntax extensions.

I wrote a minimal example here. I hope someone can help (or point me in the right direction).

```
// Just some methods collection I want to implement programmatically.
trait TraitToHack {
    fn implement_me(&self) -> int; // Say, I'd like to implement this method programmatically to return 42.
}

// I create dummy struct and wrap it with special attribute.
#[AttributeToHack(TraitToHack)]
struct StructToHack;

// I register syntax extension based on Decorator. Its signature is something like this:
// fn expand(cx: &mut ext::base::ExtCtxt, span: codemap::Span, mitem: &ast::MetaItem, item: &ast::Item, push: |P<ast::Item>|) { .. }
// This is where I got stuck :(    
fn main() {
    let hack = StructToHack;
    hack.implement_me(); // Must return 42.
}
```

The questions are:

- how to obtain Trait identifier from the AST context?
- how to get method names from that identifier and how to implement them using syntax extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Syntax extensions like macros and attributes are expanded *prior* to name resolution.  This means that whilst you could get the identifier `TraitToHack`, you wouldn't be able to extract any information about the trait from it.

The next best thing is to implement an attribute *specifically* for the trait, which has a hard-coded understanding of said trait (*i.e.* because the attribute is for `TraitToHack`, it knows it has to implement `implement_me`).  This is more or less how `deriving` works: there's a separate expansion function for each supported trait.

Comment: I presume this also means one cannot resolve the value of constants within custom attributes etc?

Comment: @eggyal No, you cannot.